# C# resource not found at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

Since a few days I get a "Resource not found" message when opening any of my xaml files, compiling and executing the application however is no problem. I am using MahApps.Metro for my UI design and already tried to clean and rebuild the whole solution and also "reinstalled" the MahApps.Metro (version 1.4.3) package using Visual Studio Blend 2015.

My App.xaml looks like this: (There are more styles defined, but the WindowStyle shows the "Resource could not be resolved" error)

```
<Application x:Class="Edge_Player.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Edge_Player"
         xmlns:metro="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
         xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         StartupUri="Player.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/Dark.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Localization/StringResources.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Icons/Icons.xaml"/>

            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/FlatButton.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/FlatSlider.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />

            <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/Base/Dark.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/Accents/Orange.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/Slider.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/Menu.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <system:Double x:Key="WindowTitleFontSize">14</system:Double>

        <BitmapImage x:Key="DesignCover" UriSource="Resources/emptyCover.png"/>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="DesignImage" UriSource="Resources/osu_mp_wallpaper.jpg"/>

        <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" 
           TargetType="{x:Type metro:MetroWindow}" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type metro:MetroWindow}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Primary}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Accent}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="GlowBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="NonActiveBorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Warn}"/>
            <Setter Property="NonActiveGlowBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Warn}"/>
            <Setter Property="NonActiveWindowTitleBrush" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"/>
            <Setter Property="WindowTitleBrush" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"/>
            <Setter Property="ShowIconOnTitleBar" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
```

All of the DynamicResources used in the "WindowStyle" are defined in a seperate file.

Comment: So when you complie, everything works fine and the resources work?
If so, try rebuilding your project and cleaning it, it usually solves such cases.

Comment: I've already tried cleaning and rebuilding, doesn't work

Comment: @Blacktasty sometimes Visual Studio needs to be closed and reopened (personal experience), have you tried that?

Comment: Visual Studio version & Mahapps version?

Comment: Visual Studio Blend 2015 with MahApps 1.4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out what caused this behaviour to occur: In the XAML editor, project code has been deactivated somehow... (I feel so stupid right now)

Comment: Also note: For projects that target ARM or X64 processors, Visual Studio cannot run project code in the designer, so the Disable project code button is disabled in the designer.

Comment: This solved my problem, but it also made the designer run incredibly slow. I turned it off again and suddenly the errors went away. Unfortunately this error returns after every single build. It always complains about a static resource key defined in a class.

Comment: Just took me half a day to figure out why my user controls had vanished one morning - eventually found that the Run Project Code setting had been switched off somehow!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, however, my project was active and in a different solution. The problem was adding a new resource to an existing project. The resources from the preexisting worked in design and run-time, but only run-time for the new resource file.

The solution was easy. I removed the .sou file or the .vs folder (depending on version) and all my resources worked in design time.

The .sou or .vs is the root of all evil in the world today when they go wrong. Removing them resolves so many issues. I should have tried this first.

Comment: +1 THIS my friend solved my problem. I kept having issues updating localization and other static resources in VS2022 and deleting the .vs fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

After few hours i found out that problem is Platform Target set to x64.

After changing it to AnyCPU the resources in design works..